# nhibernate nuget - schema not found

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I started a asp.net mvc Project and I am trying to use nibernate for db Access.

I get the following warings in visual studio:

```
Could not find schema information for the element 'urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2:hibernate-configuration'.   
Could not find schema information for the element 'urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2:session-factory'.
Could not find schema information for the element 'urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2:property'.  
Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. 
Could not find schema information for the element 'urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2:property'.  
Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. 
Could not find schema information for the element 'urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2:property'.  
Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'.
```

My Web.conf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
  </configSections>
....
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string_name">MainDb</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
...
```

I installed nhibernate via nuget.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you can simply ignore that.

But if you want, you can add the schema to your xml validation in visual studio.
XML Menu > Schemas > Add

Pick nhibernate-configuration.xsd from your packages folder

> packages\NHibernate\lib\<.NetVersion>

Now VS should be able to validate your xml (web.config) correctly.